# Delete All Array Elements With Animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native todo list app.
The task items are represented by an array using useState which is declared as follows:

```js
const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState([]);
```

I'm trying to add a function that deletes all of the items but instead of just setting it like this `setTaskItems([])`, which simply deletes all items at once, I was hoping to delete  the items one at a time starting from the end to create a more animated look.

```js
while(taskItems.length > 0)
     { 
        alert(taskItems.length);
        let itemsCopy = [...taskItems];
        itemsCopy.splice(-1);
        setTaskItems(itemsCopy);
        //setTimeout(function(){},180);
      }
```

For some reason the above code causes infinite recursion. If I remove the while loop then the *deleteAll* function does indeed remove the last item in the list. Based on my placing the *alert* at the beginning of the function it seems like the length of the array is never decreased.

Why is that?

And is there a better way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1):

It happen because in your code `taskItem` value doesn't change when you use `setTaskItems`

`setTaskItems` is an asynchronous function and the updated value of the state property change after the rerender of the component

you can try something like this

```
const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState([]);
const [deleteAll, setDeleteAll] = useState(false)


useEffect(() => {
  if(!deleteAll) return;
  if(taskItems.lenght === 0){
   setDeleteAll(false)
   return;
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
     setTaskItems(t => t.slice(0, -1))
  }, 180)
  
}, [deleteAll, taskItems])



const handleDeleteAll = () => {
 seDeleteAll(true)
}
```

Comment: this seems to work but it takes almost a full second from when I press the button until it starts deleting (I have the timeout set to 0.002). Is this just how react works with rerendering or is there something I can do?

Answer (score 1):

That is because `taskItems` value is retrieved from closure, meaning you can not expect value to be changed during handler execution. Closure recreates only after element rerenders, meaning you can access new state value only in next function execution - during the function execution value of the state never change.

You just need to assign length value to some temp variable, and use it as start/stop indicator for while loop:

```
let itemsCount = taskItems.length;
while(itemsCount > 0)
 { 
    // Here use itemsCount to determine how much you would need to slice taskItems array
    itemsCount -= 1;
  }
```

**UPDATED**

An idea of how you should do it is:

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

  const deleteAll = () => {
    let counter = items.length;

    while (counter > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setItems((p) => [...p.slice(0, counter - 1)]);
      }, counter * 1000);

      counter -= 1;
    }
  };
```

It is important to multiply timeout delay with length, in order to avoid simultaneous execution of all timeouts - you need one by one to be deleted.
Also you should clear timeout on unmount or something like that.

Comment: In that case how will this solution solve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: It avoids the infinite recursion but it doesn't seem to create the animate look I'm trying to achieve

Comment: I would need to see how you reimplemented it in order to help you.. Anyway you can also achieve  it with `useEffect`, as previous comment suggest to you. It is far more cleaner when it is done inside one function call, but because of react nature sometimes we are forced to split responsibility between handler and useEffect.

Comment: I will update answer with working implementation so you can get idea how to do it.

Comment: what "animated look" you're thinking of? fading? sliding? other?

Answer (score 1):

Due to asynchronous nature of React useState hook, you need to harness useEffect to do the job. Here's working example of removing all tasks with a 1000 ms delay between items.

```
function TasksGrid() {

    const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
    const [runDeleteAll, setRunDeleteAll] = useState(false);

    useEffect(
        () => {
            if (runDeleteAll) {
                if (taskItems.length > 0)
                    setTimeout(() => setTaskItems(taskItems.slice(0, taskItems.length - 1)), 1000);
                else
                    setRunDeleteAll(false);
            }
        },
        [runDeleteAll, taskItems]
    )

    const handleOnClick = () => {
        setRunDeleteAll(true);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {taskItems.map((taskItem, idx) => <p key={idx}>task {taskItem}</p>)}
            <button onClick={handleOnClick}>delete all</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I think I saw your comment about initial delay of removing the first item. yes, it's caused by setTimeout waiting 1000 ms to fire. To get the 1st item removed immediately I should redesign the app to remove the first item immediately, then the rest - basing on setTimeout.